# Does KillDisk use existing commands on a server to encrypt the data?

Tags: encryption, malware, linux, exploit, disk-encryption

I've been reading up on this KillDisk exploit for Linux.

https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/killdisk-ransomware-now-targets-linux-prevents-boot-up-has-faulty-encryption/

Does anyone know exactly how it works to encrypt a linux servers contents? Specifically, does it come with its own set of built in commands to do its work or does it leverage the host systems existing commands?

My thought here is that if it leverages the host systems commands and does not install its own, it may be of benefit to either remove them or lock them down, thus preventing killdisk from doing its work.

Comment: A 3DES implementation is not hard; I would expect that it's either self-contained or (worst case) uses the system OpenSSL libraries (which you can't remove without breaking lots and lots of things...)